# Access switch and textfield in tableview from another method

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tags, uiswitch

I'm having a tableview with a couple of cells with 4 uiswitches and one textfield inside. Simple question. I need a way to read all the positions of the switches and the string inside the textview by clicking a button. Tableview, textfield, switches and button is working fine. Just need to access the values of the switches and textfield from another method. By tagging the switches or something.

So how can I access the values from another method. Something like in tableview method:

...

```
    UISwitch *switchView = [[option1 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    switchView.tag = 3000;

    cell.accessoryView = switchView;
```

...

And something like this in the button method:

...

```
BOOL status = [self.view viewWithTag:3000].on; //*Not a working method*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the same class, nop ?

So maybe you could put your switch & co as class variable (declared in the header file). It would be easier ^^

Comment: Simple, good idea. But how would put the declared uiswitch in the tableview. In header: UISwitch *switch1;        In tableview-method:   cell.accessoryView = switch1;          In method to look at the switchs status: if (switch1.on == YES ) ??? Is not working. Switch doesnt get included in tableview correct.